# Create a simple array with a List or a Set

Tags: java, arrays

First of all, I have created the object Sample, which looks like this:

```
public class Sample extends Model implements Comparable<Sample>{

public String content;

public Sample(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
}
```

Then, I create a List of Sample elements. After all that, what I'd like is to be able to create a simple String array in order to store this string content elements into a simple array to render it. My idea is to do something like:

```
String[] array = ...;
render(array);
```

With each component of this string being the content field of each Sample element. By doing that, I could "transfer" this array to operate with it later. How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Java 8:

```
List<Sample> sampleList = ...;
String[] array = sampleList.stream()
    .map(Sample::getContent)
    .toArray(size -> new String[size]);
```

Using Java 7 or prior:

```
List<Sample> sampleList = ...;
String[] array = new String[sampleList.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Sample sample : sampleList) {
    array[i++] = sample.getContent();
}
```

Comment: How strange, it got rid of the error but when I do the render(array) to "transfer" its content, in the html file that receives it, it tells me that array is undefined when I do var test = array; . Maybe I have to declare something in the html file that receives the render before assigning it... Do you have any idea?

Comment: Currently, your question is how to create an array from the values of a field of a class in a list and my answer covers that. For your new problem, we would need to check what you're doing on both server and client side, but that's offtopic for the current state of the question. Since that's a different problem, I recommend you to create a new question to address that problem.

Comment: It seems that when I load the variable I get something like this: test= [Ljava.lang.String;@..., instead of the contents as strings. Do you have any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like you're storing the string representation of the array. Use a Json library to create a json string to convert the array into a proper json representation, then store that json string as request attribute or response content.

Answer (score 0):

Use toArray() method forconverting Array to arraylist.

```
// create an empty array list with an initial capacity
   ArrayList<Strng> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();

   // use add() method to add values in the list
   arrlist.add("Anil");
   arrlist.add("Vinod");
   arrlist.add("Jaya");
   arrlist.add("Arun");


   // toArray copies content into other array
   String list2[] = new String[arrlist.size()];
   list2 = arrlist.toArray(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion , if all you need is to create an array of contents , why not create a List from the Sample object and then invoke .toArray(). Did I miss something here ?